# how to compare a returnobject value with session attribute with @PostAuthorize

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to find a way  to compare a returnobject value with session attribute using @PostAuthorize

```
 @PostAuthorize("returnObject.present and returnObject.get().clientid == @userProfileRepository.findById(authentication.name).get().clientid")
    @GetMapping("/api/inventory/collateraldetail/{id}")
    public Optional<InventoryCollateralDetail> getInventoryCollateralDetails(@PathVariable("id") @NotNull Integer id) {
        return inventoryCollateralDetailService.getInventoryCollateralDetail(id);
    }
```

I am not totally sure if it is possible but an open to any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi David, welcome. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Hi @WurmD thanks for the reply. It works but I am trying to find a solution by using a session attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the `HttpSession` object in your `Controller` and then reference it in the SpEL expression.

```java
@PostAuthorize("returnObject.present and " +
        "returnObject.get().clientid == #httpSession.getAttribute('SOME_ATTRIBUTE')")
@GetMapping("/api/inventory/collateraldetail/{id}")
public Optional<InventoryCollateralDetail> getInventoryCollateralDetails(
        @PathVariable("id") @NotNull Integer id,
        HttpSession httpSession) {
    return inventoryCollateralDetailService.getInventoryCollateralDetail(id);
}
```